# postfix incoming emails

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, postfix

Where do i find incoming emails?, i mean in their txt format, i have search in /var/spool/postix/incoming  but the folder is always empty. ubuntu 10.04.4

thanks

Comment: provide proper info of user for which you want to find mails first?

Comment: A user who has a email account on the server, what else could it be?

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you mean by "incoming e-mails"? Postfix either forwards mail (if it's not the final destination for that mail), or delivers it to a mailbox (if it is the final destination). How and whereto the delivery happens is defined in your Postfix configuration. Show the output of `postconf -n` if you want someone to look at it.

Comment: here is my output:    http://pastebin.com/bLDkFnJP

Comment: From your config: `mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail`. That's where your local mailboxes are.

Comment: ok, so "mail" is a symbolik link, if i dowload it a named 'storage' folder is created on my desktop with inside a mail folder but nothing inside it.

Comment: Use `ls -l /var/spool/mail` to find out where the symbolic link points to. Then check that location.

Comment: ok , so i got: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 May  5  2010 mail -> ../mail
now this mail folder it points: it has inside one file that shows as type binary on my sftp and if i download it a "storage" folder is created on my desktop with no emails inside.